# CMS for video courses

Tags: open-source, video, cms, self-hosted

I'm looking for an open source content management system to create a site to sell my training videos (video tutorials).

- have a media player in there
- list of videos to display
- there are free courses available; non-paid training videos can be purchased
- can be hosted in Linux

Something similar to what **Lynda.com** does when it comes to training.

Do you know anything?

Answer (score 1):

[OpenEdx](https://open.edx.org/) is what you're looking for. It's the open-source software that powers EdX, one of the most popular MOOC platforms.

There are also free and paid [OpenEdX service providers](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/COMM/pages/65667081/Open+edX+Service+Providers) if you don't want to go through the trouble of setting it up.